# Mixing server variables in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In my view,

id = "Result @result"

Rendered html is

```
id="Result 123"
```

But how to get id without space

```
id = "Result123"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
id = "Result@(result)"
```

See this [C# Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) for more helpful examples.